# Define size of vector of vector of vector at the time of declaration

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, size

Recently i had a chance to use `vector<vector<vector<Some_Struct>>> threeFoldVec`,
We had to push this into a `list`. The size `threeFoldVec` is known at the time of initialization.

I am aware of how to define size of 2_fold vector at the time of declaration.

```
std::vector<std::vector<SomeStruct>> Layer_1(10, std::vector<SomeStruct>(5));
```

But when it comes to 3_fold vector, i'm confused.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<SomeStruct>>> 
                       Layer_1(10, std::vector<std::vector<SomeStruct>>(10));
```

This way I can go upto second dimension. I can obviously loop through `Layer_1` and use `resize` or `reserve` as needed, I am interested in doing it in-place, just because i think it is complex-cool.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Is a `SingleNeuron` the same as a `SomeStruct`?

Comment: @Beta Hopefully is just a typo, as otherwise it will be impossible to declare it, since the types won't match.

Comment: yeah.. it was typo.. now corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector< SomeStruct >>> 
    Layer_1(10, std::vector<std::vector< SomeStruct >>(20, std::vector< SomeStruct >(30)));
```

This will create a `10 x 20 x 30` multi-dimensional array. Note that it is extremely inefficient to use nested vectors, it is much better to use a 1D flat vector and use a 3D addressing scheme, i.e. for an array of size `HEIGHT x ROWS x COLS`, you address the logical element `[i][j][k]` as

```
[i][j][k] -> i * ROWS * COLS  + j * COLS + k
```

This will guarantee your objects are stored contiguously, hence your access time will be way better.

Comment: thx.. got it.. will definitely try 1D vector alternative. If done, i'll post peformance of both implementations